# Using same API endpoint for both guest and user in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, jwt, passport-jwt

I'm developing hotel booking portal where registration is optional. In angular application every route are public and guest can search and book hotel, and if the user is logged in then I'll be passing JWT token in the header. In NestJS (NodeJS) back-end I need to allow both user and guest to access the same endpoint like hotel-search and hotel-book. I'm using `passport-jwt` as Auth Guard, which will throw unauthorized if no token is present in the header. How to enable same route for registered and guest users?

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint is going to be accessed by both guest and logged in user, make it open route, and render frontend based on local storage/cookie data for the logged user you will have some properties for a guest you will not

Comment: I was able to achieve this by extending `AuthGuard` and adding new authentication logic inside it

Comment: @SuroorAhmmad if you could share your code or point to the resource that describes the solution it would be helpful for other users who face the same issue.

Comment: @Juriy Sure, I'll post my solution here